# keras understanding Word Embedding Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word-embedding

From the [page](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/) I got the below code:

```
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
# define documents
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']
# define class labels
labels = array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
# integer encode the documents
vocab_size = 50
encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in docs]
print(encoded_docs)
# pad documents to a max length of 4 words
max_length = 4
padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
print(padded_docs)
# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
# fit the model
model.fit(padded_docs, labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_docs, labels, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %f' % (accuracy*100))
```

1. I looked at `encoded_docs` and noticed that words `done` and `work` both have  one_hot encoding of 2, why? Is it because `unicity of word to index mapping non-guaranteed.` as per this [page](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#one_hot)?
2. I got `embeddings` by command `embeddings = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]`. in such case why do we get `embedding` object of size 50? Even though two words have same one_hot number, do they have different embedding?
3. how could i understand which embedding is for which word i.e. `done` vs `work`
4. I also found below code at the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235118/how-to-get-word-vectors-from-keras-embedding-layer) that could help with finding embedding of each word. But i dont know how to create `word_to_index`

   `word_to_index` is a mapping (i.e. dict) from words to their index, e.g. `love`: 69
   words_embeddings = {w:embeddings[idx] for w, idx in word_to_index.items()}
5. Please ensure that my understanding of `para #` is correct.

The first layer has 400 parameters because total word count is 50 and embedding have 8 dimensions so 50*8=400.

The last layer has 33 parameters because each sentence has 4 words max. So 4*8 due to dimensions of embedding and 1 for bias. 33 total

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param#   
=================================================================
embedding_3 (Embedding)      (None, 4, 8)              400       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
```

6. Finally, if 1 above is correct, is there a better way to get embedding layer `model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))`
    without doing one hot coding `encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in docs]`

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
update - providing the updated code

```
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
# define documents
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']
# define class labels
labels = array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])


from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer()

#this creates the dictionary
#IMPORTANT: MUST HAVE ALL DATA - including Test data
#IMPORTANT2: This method should be called only once!!!
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(docs)

#this transforms the texts in to sequences of indices
encoded_docs2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(docs)

encoded_docs2

max_length = 4
padded_docs2 = pad_sequences(encoded_docs2, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
max_index = array(padded_docs2).reshape((-1,)).max()



# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_index+1, 8, input_length=max_length))# you cannot use just max_index 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
# fit the model
model.fit(padded_docs2, labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_docs2, labels, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %f' % (accuracy*100))

embeddings = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]

embeding_for_word_7 = embeddings[14]
index = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([['well']])[0][0]
tokenizer.document_count
tokenizer.word_index
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1 - Yes, word unicity is not guaranteed, see the [docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text):

- From `one_hot`: This is a wrapper to the `hashing_trick` function...
- From `hashing_trick`: "Two or more words may be assigned to the same index, due to **possible collisions by the hashing function**. The probability of a collision is in relation to the dimension of the hashing space and the number of distinct objects."

It would be better to use a `Tokenizer` for this. (See question 4)

**It's very important to remember** that you should involve **all words at once** when creating indices. You cannot use a function to create a dictionary with 2 words, then again with 2 words, then again.... This will create very wrong dictionaries.

---

2 - Embeddings have the size `50 x 8`, because that was defined in the embedding layer:

```
Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length)
```

- `vocab_size = 50` - this means there are 50 words in the dictionary
- `embedding_size= 8` - this is the true size of the embedding: each word is represented by a vector of 8 numbers.

---

3 - You don't know. They use the same embedding.

The system will use the same embedding (the one for index = 2). This is not healthy for your model at all. You should use another method for creating indices in question 1.

---

4 - You can create a word dictionary manually, or use the `Tokenizer` class.

**Manually**:

Make sure you remove punctuation, make all words lower case.

Just create a dictionary for each word you have:

```
dictionary = dict()
current_key = 1

for doc in docs:
    for word in doc.split(' '):
        #make sure you remove punctuation (this might be boring)
        word = word.lower()

        if not (word in dictionary):
            dictionary[word] = current_key
            current_key += 1
```

**Tokenizer:**

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer()

#this creates the dictionary
#IMPORTANT: MUST HAVE ALL DATA - including Test data
#IMPORTANT2: This method should be called only once!!!
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(docs)

#this transforms the texts in to sequences of indices
encoded_docs2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(docs)
```

See the output of `encoded_docs2`:

```
[[6, 2], [3, 1], [7, 4], [8, 1], [9], [10], [5, 4], [11, 3], [5, 1], [12, 13, 2, 14]]
```

See the maximum index:

```
padded_docs2 = pad_sequences(encoded_docs2, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
max_index = array(padded_docs2).reshape((-1,)).max()
```

So, your `vocab_size` should be 15 (otherwise you'd have lots of useless - and harmless - embedding rows). Notice that `0` was not used as an index. It will appear in padding!!!

> Do not "fit" the tokenizer again! Only use `texts_to_sequences()` or other methods [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py) that are not related to "fitting".

**Hint:** it might be useful to include `end_of_sentence` words in your text sometimes.

**Hint2:** it is a good idea to save your `Tokenizer` to be used later (since it has a specific dictoinary for your data, created with `fit_on_texts`).

```
#save:
text_to_save = tokenizer.to_json()

#load:
from keras.preprocessing.text import tokenizer_from_json
tokenizer = tokenizer_from_json(loaded_text)
```

---

5 - Params for embedding are correct.

**Dense:**

Params for `Dense` are always based on the preceding layer (the `Flatten` in this case).

The formula is: `previous_output * units + units`

This results in `32 (from the Flatten) * 1 (Dense units) + 1 (Dense bias=units) = 33`

**Flatten:**

It gets all the previous dimensions multiplied = `8 * 4`.
The `Embedding` outputs `lenght = 4` and `embedding_size = 8`.

---

6 - The `Embedding` layer is not dependent of your data and how you preprocess it.

The `Embedding` layer has simply the size 50 x 8 because you told so. (See question 2)

There are, of course, better ways of preprocessing the data - See question 4.

This will lead you to select better the `vocab_size` (which is dictionary size).

### Seeing the embedding of a word:

Get the embeddings matrix:

```
embeddings = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
```

Choose any word index:

```
embeding_for_word_7 = embeddings[7]
```

That's all.

If you're using a tokenizer, get the word index with:

```
index = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([['word']])[0][0]
```

Comment: I am going through your answer. Thanks for a detailed reply. Would it be possible to provide complete code that includes answers 3 and 4?

Comment: i used your suggestions. I noticed that i have to use `model.add(Embedding(max_index+1, 8, input_length=max_length))` instead of `model.add(Embedding(max_index, 8, input_length=max_length))`. `max_index` is 14 and we added `0` for padding...is that adjustment correct?